# Good way to split the same value text from few files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, merge

I have 3 files, and splitting few values from it.

```
file1: data1, data11, TEST (3 dimension with 2000 value each)
file2: data2, TEST, data22 (3 dimension with 1500 value each)
file3: TEST, data3, data33, data3333, data33333 (5 dimension with 3000 value each)
```

In first case, i'm comparing file1[2] to file2[1], if the same text value is founding, i'm merging this two lines (from 2 files).
Next step is comparing result of merging with file3[0], and the same scenario, if find the same text value, i'm merging result with last file.

I'm doing this with help for loops, but this take to long time:

```
for i in range(len(limit_value_text)):
   for g in range(len(driver_id)):
      if variables_driver_id[k] == driver_id[g]:
        data[4].append(driver_name[g].text)
        data[5].append(driver_module[g].text)
for g in range(len(limit_value_text)):
   for j in range(len(key_words[0])):
      if limit_value_text[g].text == key_words[0][j]:
         data[6].append(key_words[1][j])
```

One file is a CSV file and two oders are XML files.‬
In XML files I'm using XPath to find only this tags with I want to have.‬

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use more loops your execution time will be more.

For that `pandas` would be the better alternative for this.
Please create `dataframes`  for your `files (file1, file2, file3)`.
If you are having `csv` files, use below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep=',', header = 0)
```

**Refer:** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Then do the comparison between the `dataframes (files)` and perform merge `(pandas has merge and concat features)`. This will improve your execution time. Please give a try.

Comment: One file is a CSV file and two oders are XML files.

Comment: In XML files I'm using XPath to find only this tags with I want to have.